# Ошибка: Index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, исключения, index

Что не так с кодом?

***Есть таблица:***

```
try{

            statm.execute("CREATE TABLE `player` (`id_player` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `surname` VARCHAR(85) NOT NULL, "
                    + "`name` VARCHAR(85) NOT NULL, `patronymic` VARCHAR(85) NOT NULL, `birth_date` DATE NOT NULL, `height` int(20) NOT NULL,"
                    + "`weight` int(20) NOT NULL, `teamP` VARCHAR(85) NOT NULL,"
                    + "`date_pr` DATE NOT NULL, `amplua` VARCHAR (85) NOT NULL, `personal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,"
                    + " PRIMARY KEY(id_player))");
            statm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `player` (`surname`, "
                    + "`name`, `patronymic`, `birth_date`, `height`,"
                    + "`weight`, `teamP`,"
                    + "`date_pr`, `amplua`, `personal_id`) VALUES ('Arktaev', 'Viktor', 'Vladimirovich', '1990-06-28', "
                    + "'180', '80', 'Spartak', '2015-02-17', 'Offence', '6'),"
                    + "('Babakin', 'Sergey', 'Andreevich', '1985-11-15', "
                    + "'182', '76', 'Squirells', '2015-02-18', 'Defence', '4')"); 

        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            Connect.tp_sost.setText("Ошибка create table player");
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
```

***Есть запрос DESCRIBE.***

```
try{
            res = statm.executeQuery("DESCRIBE player");

            while(res.next()){
                System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2) + "\t" + res.getString(3) + "\t" + res.getString(4)
                + "\t" + res.getString(5) + "\t" + res.getString(6) +"\t" + res.getString(7)+ "\t" + res.getString(8) 
                + "\t" + res.getString(9)+ res.getString(10)+ res.getString(11) + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            Connect.tp_sost.setText("Ошибка player");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

            return;
    }
```

Получаю:

**Ошибка player

Column Index out of range, 7 > 6.**

Comment: А что по вашему должны получать те getstring. я что то сомневаюсь, что describe возвращает аж 11 колонок

Comment: @Mike они должны вернуть инфу о каждой колонке в таблице

Comment: что ж сомневаться, если вон они все создаются

Comment: @post_zeew атрибуты - это столбцы? 11, значит

Comment: Грубо говоря, `DESCRIBE player` возвращает таблицу, в которой 11 строк и 6 столбцов, а не наоборот.

Comment: @post_zeew ааа, я понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE player` выдает описание таблицы, а не записи
В описании таблицы 6 столбцов

`SELECT * FROM  player;` пробуй.

Comment: SELECT я отдельно делаю, да; 
на данном этапе я хочу получить вывод именно описания таблицы

Comment: SELECT то работает у меня, а вот DESCRIBE - нет

Comment: тебе возвращается таблица из 6 столбцов (он даже в описании ошибки тебе написал), а в обработке запроса ты спрашиваешь аж 11 столбцов. Вот на запросе 7-го столбца ошибка и вылетает. Попробуй руками запрос написать в SQL, посмотри, что отвечает сервер.

Comment: понял, сейчас попробую